# help me, I have a trouble in compile freerdp in ubuntu 16.04 lts

Tags: 16.04

I'm compiling freerdp in ubuntu 16.04 lts.

[FreeRDP GitHub page](https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/wiki/Compilation)

make and make install and run ldconfig, after I confirm `/usr/local/bin/xfreerdp` created xfreerdp directory.

However "Plugins are installed in `/usr/local/lib/freerdp`" this step, I didn't see anything even freerdp directory.

How can I Plugins are installed. 
 I think run ldconfig , after plugins and freerdp exec file created. but `/usr/local/bin/xfreerdp` is craeted but plugins are not installed or created

Comment: I have exactly the same issue with Ununtu 14.04 so would think the instructions are missing a step.